# Как вывести определенное количество файлов, самых новых по дате модификации, из директории “/path/to/directory/”, имя которых начинается на “G456”?

Tags: linux, shell, rhel

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести определенное количество файлов(например 20), самых новых по дате модификации, из директории “/path/to/directory/”, имя которых начинается на “G456”?
Кусочно понимаю, составить не получается.

Comment: `ls -l --sort=time /path/to/directory/G456* | head -n 20`

Comment: @PotroNik, Если файлов по маске миллионов десять, то не получится ничего. Правильный ответ `man find`.